# Fastest way to check if any point from a list is in bwteen two fixed points A and B

Tags: python, algorithm, filter

I have two large sets of points L1 and L2 and a fixed point B. I need an efficient way to filter L1 and remove all points which their path (straight line) to B is blocked by any point from L2.

I tried the following:

```
# Measure distance between two points
def distance (p1, p2):
    return ((p2[1] - p1[1])**2 + (p2[0] - p1[0])**2)**0.5

# Check if point c is on same line between points a and b
def inBetween (a, b, c):
    return distance (a, b) == distance (a, c) + distance (b, c)

def isPathBlocked (L1, L2, B):
    for A in L1:
        for C in L2:
            if inBetween (A, B, C):
                print "path blocked"
```

Although it works but it's very CPU intensive considering that L1 and L2 can have more than 50,000 points in each and therefor the nested loops would execute 50,000 * 50,000 times. Is there a better way to do this or any good algorithm that I can use here?

## Note:

I should have mentioned earlier but all points coords in L1 and L2 are integers.

## Note 2:

B has integers coords and all points in L1 and L2 are within a certain radius from B (radius is about 10 to 10000).

## Solutions:

Thanks to the great answers below I'm here adding an example of how to use the main two methods provided (hash and compare, sort and merge compare) with thorough explanation for those who are new to algorithms which might find it useful:

```
l1 = [(x,y) for x in range (10) for y in range(10)]
l2 = [(5,3), (5,1), (8,2), (4,3), (1,5), (3,5), (7,7), (3,7)]
b = (5,5)

# instead of using atan2 to calculate polar angles, to improve performance we only 
# calculate (y/x, x>0) which has a unique value for different angles
# if x == 0 (angle is eigher 90 or -90 degrees) then we use (None, y>0) instead
def toPolar (p1, p2):
    if p2[0] != p1[0]:
        return (float (p2[1] - p1[1]) / float (p2[0] - p1[0]), p2[0] < p1[0])
    if p2[1] != p1[1]:
        return (None, p2[1] < p1[1])

# Check if b is between a and c, we don't need to check if they
# are cllinear because they are already when they have same polar angle
def inBetween (a, b, c):
    if a[0] <= b[0] <= c[0] or c[0] <= b[0] <= a[0]:
        return a[1] <= b[1] <= c[1] or c[1] <= b[1] <= a[1]
    return False

# b stationary point, l1 the points of interest, l2 blockers
def hashFilter (b, l1, l2):
    hashTable = {}
    # create a hash table of l2 points using polar angles as keys,
    # if two points have the same polar angle keep only the one that
    # is closer to b
    for blocker in l2:
        key = toPolar (b, blocker)
        prev = hashTable.get (key)
        if prev == None or inBetween (b, blocker, prev):
            hashTable[key] = blocker
    unBlocked = []
    blocked = []
    # Remove the points from l1 if they are blocked by any point from l2
    for point in l1:
        key = toPolar (b, point)
        blocker = hashTable.get (key)
        if blocker == None or not inBetween (b, blocker, point):
            unBlocked.append (point)
        else: blocked.append (point)
    return sorted (blocked)

def sortFilter (b, l1, l2):
    # Convert cartesian to polar (sort of)
    points = [(toPolar(b, x), x) for x in l1]
    # Sort using polar angle as key
    points = sorted (points, key = lambda x: x[0])
    # Convert cartesian to polar (sort of)
    blockers = [(toPolar(b, x), x) for x in l2]
    # Sort using polar angle as key
    blockers = sorted (blockers, key = lambda x: x[0])
    unBlocked = []
    blocked = []
    ind = 0
    length = len (blockers)
    for point in points:
        if ind >= length: break
        isBlocked = False
        subInd = None
        # Increase index of blockers until we reach a matching polar angle
        while ind < length and blockers[ind][0] <= point[0]:
            if blockers[ind][0] == point[0]:
                # we need to check every point in points(l1) for being blocked
                # by comparing it to all points in blockers(l2) with
                # identical polar angle.
                # However because there could be multiple points and multiple
                # blockers with the same polar angle, we store the ind of the
                # first identical polar angle that appears in the blockers list,
                # so that the next item in points list can loop again over
                # this group of blockers
                if subInd == None: subInd = ind
                if inBetween (b, blockers[ind][1], point[1]):
                    blocked.append (point[1])
                    isBlocked = True
                    # If we found out that the point is blocked then we break
                    # out of the loop to test the next item in points
                    break
            ind += 1
        if not isBlocked: unBlocked.append (point[1])
        # Move the index back to the first item in the blockers group with
        # same polar angle to the last point checked
        if subInd != None: ind = subInd
    return sorted (blocked)

print hashFilter (b, l1, l2)
print sortFilter (b, l1, l2)
```

Comment: what if you looked at the problem in polar coordinates? you'd have to calculate `2*N` angles (this step could be done in parallel); but these could be sorted and compared more efficiently than your 2 loops?

Comment: ok - thanks for the update on the benchmark! will try to make a small example or what i mean.

Comment: How close does C have to be to the line AB to count as being on the line?

Comment: @PM2Ring C should be precisely the line, the coords of the points in L1 and L2 are all integers sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: Yes, that's important information! :) I assume B also has integer coords. And it'd also be good to know what's the range of these integers.

Comment: @PM2Ring B also has integer coordinates and there's a max distance limit  (about 10 to 10000) between B and all the points in L1 and L2 which I also failed to mention sorry

Comment: Note that you don't really have to take the square root in your distance calculation. That is, if the squares are equal, then the square roots are equal. The only time you need the square root is if you really need the actual distance. But then, there are more efficient ways to determine if a point is on a line, that don't involve distance calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the constraints (small integer coordinates), we can just hash slopes instead of sorting. This depends on the facts that (1) float division is correctly rounded (2) the minimum gap between distinct fractions with denominators bounded by 10000 is at least approximately 1/10000^2, which is safely more than 1 ulp.

```
def key(b, p):
    if p[0] != b[0]:
        return (float(p[1] - b[1]) / float(p[0] - b[0]), p[0] < b[0])
    if p[1] != b[1]:
        return (None, p[1] < b[1])
    return None


def between1(b, p, q):
    return b <= p <= q or q <= p <= b


def between2_assume_collinear(b, p, q):
    return between1(b[0], p[0], q[0]) and between1(b[1], p[1], q[1])


def unblocked(b, l1, l2):
    inner = {}
    for p in l2:
        k = key(b, p)
        if k is None:
            return
        q = inner.get(k)
        if q is None or between2_assume_collinear(b, p, q):
            inner[k] = p
    for q in l1:
        p = inner.get(key(b, q))
        if p is None or not between2_assume_collinear(b, p, q):
            yield q
```

Here's some test code.

```
def demo(b, l2):
    n = 10
    l1 = [(x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)]
    grid = [[' ' for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
    for q in unblocked(b, l1, l2):
        grid[q[1]][q[0]] = '*'
    grid[b[1]][b[0]] = '@'
    for p in l2:
        grid[p[1]][p[0]] = '2'
    for row in grid:
        print(''.join(row))


demo((5, 5), [(5, 3), (5, 1), (8, 2), (4, 3), (1, 5), (3, 5)])
```

Alternative `key` function that is slower but works for all integers:

```
import fractions


def key(b, p):
    d0 = p[0] - b[0]
    d1 = p[1] - b[1]
    g = fractions.gcd(d0, d1)
    if g == 0:
        return None
    g = abs(g)
    return (d0 // g, d1 // g)
```

Comment: Good idea. I might use lowest-terms rationals instead of floating point division.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Easy enough; replace the float division by `fractions.Fraction`. I'd be shocked if that were faster though.

Comment: not as fast, but it doesn't rely on the details of the float implementation or the small int constraint

Comment: it wasn't about integers when i posted my answer. now that it is: nice idea! +1

Comment: This is considerably faster than sorting and merge compare.

Answer (score 2):

this is a mini-implementation of what i mean (it is the same as idea #2 in [MBo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo) answer):

```
import random
import math
from collections import namedtuple


Cartesian = namedtuple('Cartesian', ('x', 'y', 'sample'))
Polar = namedtuple('Polar', ('r', 'phi', 'sample'))


def to_polar(cartesian, origin):

    x_diff = cartesian.x - origin.x
    y_diff = cartesian.y - origin.y
    r = math.hypot(x_diff, y_diff)
    phi = math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff)

    return Polar(r=r, phi=phi, sample=cartesian.sample)


def to_cartesian(polar, origin):

    x = polar.r*math.cos(polar.phi) + origin.x
    y = polar.r*math.sin(polar.phi) + origin.y

    return Cartesian(x=x, y=y, sample=polar.sample)


random.seed(45432)  # get reproducibe results

SCALE = 100
N_SAMPLES = 5

B = Cartesian(x=SCALE*random.random(), y=SCALE*random.random(), sample='B')

L1_cartesian = [Cartesian(x=SCALE*random.random(),
                          y=SCALE*random.random(),
                          sample='L1')
                for _ in range(N_SAMPLES)]
L1_polar = [to_polar(cartesian=l1, origin=B) for l1 in L1_cartesian]

L2_cartesian = [Cartesian(x=SCALE*random.random(),
                          y=SCALE*random.random(),
                          sample='L2')
                for _ in range(N_SAMPLES)]
L2_polar = [to_polar(cartesian=l2, origin=B) for l2 in L2_cartesian]

all_polar = L1_polar + L2_polar
all_polar = sorted(all_polar, key=lambda x: x.phi)

print(all_polar)
```

what you get at the end is a list of all points, sorted by their angle respective to `B` (their origin sample is stored in `all_polar.sample`). you'd just have to cleverly iterate over that list; checking only angles that are 'close' (and points from different sample sets).

similar (or equal angle) then still does not mean a point is 'in between'; you'd still have to compare the distance to `B` (which is `all_polar.r`).

there is no need to join the two samples into one list; you could also iterate over one list and yield elements that are 'close' from the other list.

none of this has been throughly tested! and the comparison part is missing.

---

as you have added that your points are at integer coordinates, i suggest you do what [**David Eisenstat's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382485/4954037) suggests (this is his idea added to my code; credit should go to his answer): instead of calculating the polar coordinates, make a dictionary containing the result of this

```
from fractions import Fraction

def get_slope(cartesian, origin):
    x_diff = cartesian.x - origin.x
    y_diff = cartesian.y - origin.y

    slope = Fraction(y_diff, x_diff)
    x_sign = x_diff > 0

    return (slope, x_sign)
```

and then create a dictionary e.g. like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)
# add all the points in your sets (both)
dct[get_slope(cartesian, origin)].append(cartesian)
```

it is then trivial to compare the points for a given slope.

Comment: It might be a good idea for each Polar object to hold a reference to its Cartesian point.

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes, there is a lot room for improvement! that is one very good idea!

Answer (score 1):

1. There is more effective approach to determine whether point is between two another points - use cross product
2. For this problem does exist faster algorithmic approach with complexity O(NlogN) (while your brute force is O(N^2))

   - Sort both point sets by polar angle against point B
   - Walk though both sets in merge manner and compare angles

Answer (score 1):

What I am getting is: We have to iterate over all the points of L1 and we have to check if straight line from each and every point from L1 set to fixed point B is getting blocked by any point of the set L2 or not. If it is getting blocked then the point has to be removed from L1 set else not.

Lets consider, L1 = {(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...} and L2 = {(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ...} and the fixed point B is (m, n). So while checking if (x1, y1) point has to be removed from L1 set or not we can check -

```
if (x1 <= a1 and a1 <= m) and (y1 <= b1 and b1 <= n):
    Cartesian Product / Euclidean Distance
else:
    {L1 - (x1, y1)} // remove from L1
```

Before calculation of these heavy operations like Cartesian product or distance finding between two points, this condition for all the points of L2 can be checked. Because one point (a1, b1) can come in in between (x1, y1) and (m, n) these two points only if that condition becomes true. Theoretically this will still be O(N^2)) but practically the complexity will be lesser than O(N^2)).